# How to monitor http requests in order to see my header request in my ios app built in react native

Tags: ios, iphone, ajax, http, react-native

I am developing an IOS app using React Native and I am trying to figure out how to monitor my http requests which comes out from my app to my server.
I tried looking in Network tab in the chrome but I didn't see my ajax requests.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Charles Web Debugging Proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com)

Answer (score 1):

You can turn on http logging at your server end. Server's can log the whole request payload. If you don't have access to the server, then you can use a passthrough proxy to capture the requests as well.